# Installing fonts in NSIS

Tags: fonts, installation, nsis

I want to be able to install a font. Instead of using all these complicated ways:
[1](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Register_Fonts)
[2](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Advanced_Font_Installation)

Could i just copy my ".ttf" file to $FONTS

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation for [AddFontResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you will see this note at the end:

> This function installs the font only for the current session. When the
>   system restarts, the font will not be present. To have the font
>   installed even after restarting the system, the font must be listed in
>   the registry.

If you think the examples on the wiki are too complicated you could reduce the amount of code if:

- You don't support Win9x
- You don't need the font right away and can wait for a reboot
- You don't need the font after a reboot (Unlikely)

No matter how you look at it, you have to call AddFontResource+WM_FONTCHANGE or add a entry in the registry. Most installers require both, therefore the example scripts do both.

If you don't want to do any of this you could maybe try to simulate a user copy to the font folder by using the [CopyFiles](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.3.2) command (I have never tried this and I don't know if Windows will notice the new font).

Comment: what about this? "FontName plugin"

Comment: "This script is now included in the FontName plugin by default" So..?